# PowerShell: Split user defined distinguished name into individual parts

Tags: string, powershell, join, split, distinguishedname

I have a GUI that accepts a few DNs from the user. I know how to get the text, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to split this DN up into its individual parts. The number of parts might vary. For example:

```
$string1 = "ou=this,ou=is,dc=a,dc=string"
$string2 = "ou=this,ou=is,ou=another,dc=dn,dc=string
```

What I'm trying to do is separate the ou's from the dc's and create the ou's if they don't exist. I just can't figure out how to separate the ou's from the dc's and make them into separate strings so I'll be left with:

```
$newString1 = "ou=this,ou=is"
$newString2 = "dc=a,dc=string"
$newString3 = "this,ou=is,ou=another"
$newString4 = "dc=dn,dc=string
```

I know I can split the strings by using `$string1.Split(",")`, but I'm at a loss at this point how to store the individual values in a new variable. I'm fairly new to PowerShell, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I know I can create the ou's just from the information I have, but I need them separated for other work that's going to be done in the code. Would also be nice to see them split up such that I can grab the ou's individually.

Comment: You should be editing these additional notes into your question rather than adding comments.  Also, are you operating on exactly two distinguished names?  Or is there a variable number, say, read in from a file?  Having `$newString1` through `$newString4` variables is fine if you have 2 DNs but not so much if you have 20...or 200.

Comment: I'll be getting two DNs. One for groups and one for users. I'm basically having the user define where they want groups and users to be located on an Active Directory and then have my script create those directories. All in all, I really want to learn how break up a string like this in Powershell into separate chunks given it will be user defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is helpful in terms of what's being asked.  This assumes that you want to store the relative distinguished names in two groups: those before you hit `dc=` and those after (and including) you hit `dc=`.

```
$string1 = "ou=this,ou=is,dc=a,dc=string"
$string2 = "ou=this,ou=is,ou=another,dc=dn,dc=string"

foreach ($dn in $string1, $string2)
{
    # Break the distinguished name up into a list of relative distinguished names
    $rdnList = $dn -split ',';
    $cnList = @();
    $nextIndex = 0;

    while ($nextIndex -lt $rdnList.Length)
    {
        $rdn = $rdnList[$nextIndex];
        $name, $value = $rdn -split '=';

        # Stop looping if we've hit a dc= RDN
        if ($name -eq 'dc')
        {
            break;
        }

        $cnList += $rdn;
        $nextIndex++;
    }
    # The remainder of the array is our RDN list
    $dcList = $rdnList[$nextIndex..($rdnList.Length - 1)];

    # Reassemble both lists into strings
    $cnText = $cnList -join ',';
    $dcText = $dcList -join ',';

    # The data has now been processed; print it out    
    Write-Host "`$dn: $dn";
    Write-Host "`$cnText: $cnText";
    Write-host "`$dcText: $dcText";
    Write-Host;
}
```

Output is...

```
$dn: ou=this,ou=is,dc=a,dc=string
$cnText: ou=this,ou=is
$dcText: dc=a,dc=string

$dn: ou=this,ou=is,ou=another,dc=dn,dc=string
$cnText: ou=this,ou=is,ou=another
$dcText: dc=dn,dc=string
```

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the fast reply! That was a lot harder than I thought it would be.

Comment: It is best to [avoid `Write-Host`](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @mklement0 That's just diagnostic code to show the strings before and after being split.  I don't know what the author is going to do with this but that's where they'd put their code instead to make use of those variables.

Comment: @BACON: Understood, but I still suggest not using `Write-Host` in SO answers, at least not without explanation, for fear that inexperienced users will  understandably, but mistakenly infer that `Write-Host` is the equivalent of `echo` in traditional shells. Using PowerShell's implicit default output will do just fine (and is a good concept to introduce). If you really want to show _diagnostic_ output, use `Write-Verbose -Verbose ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```powershell
# Define input strings.
$strings = 'ou=this,ou=is,dc=a,dc=string',
           'ou=this,ou=is,ou=another,dc=dn,dc=string'

foreach ($string in $strings) {

  # Split each string into the ou=... part and the dc=... part.
  $ouPart, $dcPart = $string -split ',(?=dc=)', 2

  # Now split each part into its constituent OU and DC names as arrays.
  $ous = $ouPart -split '(?:^|,)ou=' -ne '' -replace '\\'
  $dcs = $dcPart -split '(?:^|,)dc=' -ne '' -replace '\\'

  # Output result.
  [pscustomobject] @{ ouPart = $ouPart; dcPart = $dcPart; ous = $ous; dcs = $dcs}

}
```

The above yields:

```
ouPart                   dcPart          ous                 dcs         
------                   ------          ---                 ---         
ou=this,ou=is            dc=a,dc=string  {this, is}          {a, string} 
ou=this,ou=is,ou=another dc=dn,dc=string {this, is, another} {dn, string}
```

**Explanation:**

- `$string -split ',(?=dc=)', 2` splits the input string into 2 parts, by the first occurrence of substring `,dc=`. Only the `,` between the 2 halves is removed, because the `(?=...)` - a (positive) lookahead assertion - *matches* the enclosed expression, but doesn't *capture* it; in this case, it ensures that the 2nd half still starts with `dc=`.
- `$ouPart, $dcPart = ...` assigns the elements of the 2-element array that `-split` returns to individual variables.
- `$ouPart -split '(?:^|,)ou='` splits the `ou=...,ou=...` half into an array of embedded OU names (splitting the `dc=...,dc=...` half works analogously):

  - `(?:^|,)ou=` matches `ou=` occurrences preceded either by the start of the string (`^`) or (`|`) a `,`.

    - Enclosing `^|,` in a *non-capturing* subexpression (`(?:...)`) ensures that the subexpressions aren't included in the `-split` results.
- `-ne ''` filters out empty array elements that result from the `-split` delimiter expression occurring at the *start* of the input string.
- `-replace '\\'` removes `\` instances from each name, given that they could contain `\`-escaped characters, such as a value-*embedded* `,` escaped as `\,`
- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` (PSv3+) constructs a custom object from a hashtable literal (`@{ .... }`) with the extracted values as properties.
  Note that simply not assigning the object to a variable it is *implicitly output*, and PowerShell's default output formatting automatically provides a pretty tabular representation.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting them into an array, like this:

```
c:\>$string = "ou=this,ou=is,ou=another,dc=dn,dc=string"
c:\>$array = $string.split(",")
c:\>$array
ou=this
ou=is
ou=another
dc=dn
dc=string
c:\>
```

With the array you can determine the number of elements:

```
c:\>$array.Length
5
c:\>
```

Or process it in a loop:

```
c:\> foreach ($i in $array) { $i }
ou=this
ou=is
ou=another
dc=dn
dc=string
c:\>
```

Obviously, that loop is no different to just outputting the $array variable but should provide insight into how to use the loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the foreach loop; however, how come I can't do this: 

    foreach ($i in $array) { if ($i -contains "ou") { Write-Host $i}}

I still can't figure out how to work with the separate parts. I plan on reversing the array, which I know how to do, but can't figure out how to pull out and work with the individual chuncks :(.